# Localhost unresponsive until re-binding self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, visual-studio-2022, iis-express, self-signed-certificate

Gonna preface this with saying that all of what I describe below is completely out of my comfort zone. I know absolutely nothing about how this stuff works, I only know that it *does* work.

When running IIS Express through Visual Studio 2022, I routinely (every ~4h) have to re-run the following script, and then drag the newly-generated certificate into `Trusted Root Certificate Authorities\Certificates` in order to get my browser to recognize localhost. If I don't run the script, I simply get a standard error message indicating that my browser doesn't recognize the address I'm trying to browse to.

```
# port and appId are any randomly chosen port or guid
$name = 'localhost'
$port = 12345
$appId = '626feeb6-1ee1-4670-8d38-80b8139fe8ce'

Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object { $_.Subject -eq 'CN=' + $name } | Remove-Item

$thumb=(New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName $name -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My).Thumbprint.ToLower()

Invoke-Expression "netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:$port"
Invoke-Expression "netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:$port appid='{$appId}' certhash=$thumb"
```

Does anyone know why I need to do this?

**EDIT1:**

Some more information to help debug this. Here's the output of running `netsh http show sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:$port`:

[image: netsh http show]

And here is what `certlm` shows me (second tab confirms it's got the same thumbprint as the one shown above):

[image: certlm]

Answer (score 0):

One obvious guess is that the certificate just expires.

You can check your cert expiration date with the following command in powershell

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | ForEach-Object {
     Write-Host "Certificate Subject: $($_.Subject)"
     Write-Host "Thumbprint: $($_.Thumbprint)"
     Write-Host "Expiration Date: $($_.NotAfter)"
     Write-Host "------------------------"
 }
```

If they don't expire but they still stop working for you then I am afraid we need more info. In `Trusted Root Certificate Authorities\Certificates` is the old cert still there and you just replace it with the new one or is it deleted from there in 4 hour?

Comment: Hi adam, thanks for the suggestion. I ran the query you listed, and confirmed the certificate is not expired. Also, I confirmed the certificate is indeed still in the certificate store. Lastly, I checked to see what both of those screens showed after deleting/recreating the certificates, and I see nothing different between them, other than the fact that it works after recreating. I updated my post with some screenshots, maybe there's useful information in there?